# Change value in other thread and assert the later (in the 'main' thread)

Tags: rust

Link to playground (or below is the code as well): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6a8e4e6b9fa6aa647b2651e58402aa0

I want to write a test for code from a library. The code outside the `main` method has the same structure as the library (https://github.com/housleyjk/ws-rs/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L110).

At some point, I want to supply a value that can be changed over time in a thread. I must assert that value later in a different thread. Hard part is, the instantiation of the type holding the changing value is constructed in a `FnMut` closure.

I tried moving it, I tried `RefCell`, I tried `Arc` but I failed miserably. Any suggestions?

```
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

trait Fly {}

trait Surf {
    fn will_be_called_after_two_seconds(&mut self);
}

struct Roll;

struct FlyingBird;

impl Fly for FlyingBird {}

struct SurfingDog(bool);

impl Surf for SurfingDog {
    fn will_be_called_after_two_seconds(&mut self) {
        self.0 = true;
    }
}

fn closure_boi<F, S>(x: F) where F: FnMut(Roll) -> S, S: Surf {}

fn main() {
    let val = false;

    std::thread::spawn(|| {
        closure_boi(|_| {
            SurfingDog(val)
        });
    });

    sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));

    assert_eq!(true, val);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems that can prevent the above code from working:

- Rust won't allow you to share a value between two threads if it can't prove that the threads that use it won't outlive the the value itself (in this case a scoep in `main`). The fix is to either heap-allocate the value and use [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) to track it or to create the thread using [`crossbeam_utils::thread::scope`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.3/crossbeam/thread/fn.scope.html), which does provide such a guarantee. Since you likely need the spawned thread to keep running in parallel, let's go for the `Arc`.
- `SurfingDog` can't just contain a boolean, it must either contain a *reference* to a boolean, or the whole `SurfingDog` instance must be available in `main`. In the current code, the boolean modified by the other thread resides in the `SurfingDog` value `closure_boi` obtains from the closure it receives, which is a distinct value from the `val` checked in `main`.
- Rust won't allow the other thread to *modify* the value the first thread is reading without synchronization because that would constitute a [data race](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/races.html). The fix is to either use a lock like [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) or an atomic type like [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html).

Taking the above into account, here is a modification of the code that compiles and works ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3e832f256fe3cb84a13c6a2e611905a)):

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

trait Surf {
    fn will_be_called_after_two_seconds(&mut self);
}

struct SurfingDog<'a>(&'a Mutex<bool>);

impl<'a> Surf for SurfingDog<'a> {
    fn will_be_called_after_two_seconds(&mut self) {
        let mut state = self.0.lock().unwrap();
        *state = true;
    }
}

fn closure_boi<S: Surf>(mut x: impl FnMut() -> S) {
    let mut surfer = x();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
    surfer.will_be_called_after_two_seconds();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(10)); // keep running
}

fn main() {
    let val = Arc::new(Mutex::new(false));
    std::thread::spawn({
        let val = Arc::clone(&val);
        move || {
            closure_boi(|| SurfingDog(&*val));
        }
    });
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
    assert_eq!(true, *val.lock().unwrap());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I just can not get it working with the code I linked in my question. This is a reproduction path: https://github.com/Jasperav/ClosureRust, just 1 dependency and some code in main.rs. This is the error: expected an `FnOnce<()>` closure, found `()`. Also, are there references to the syntax you are using, because I haven't seen it in the Rust Book?: the use of move before || and omitting the || after calling the spawn method. Putting back the initial || in the spawn closure will throw a different error in my project though :(

Comment: @J.Doe You have an extra semicolon after the closure, so `spawn` doesn't receive the closure, but the implicit empty tuple. In my code a similar construct works because I put braces around the closure body, allowing you to add things other than the call to `closure_boi`. But note that there is no semicolon *after* the closing (inner) brace, which ensures that the closure (the last expression in the outer brace) is actually passed to `thread::spawn`.

Comment: `move` before `||` should be covered by any decent rust book, e.g. O'Reilly's "Programming Rust" or the official book [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch13-01-closures.html#capturing-the-environment-with-closures). It just tells the closure to move the captured variables into it, rather than keep a reference.

Comment: `{ ... }` passed to `thread::spawn` is allowed because every Rust block is an expression evaluating to the last expression inside it, which in my code is the closure. The block enclosed in braces came useful to "prepare" the cloned `val` to move into the closure. I could have written the same thing [like this](https://pastebin.com/1yRVTz1j), but the formulation in the answer is somewhat more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation :)